how to make black formatter extension work
I am windows users and I want to use black formatter in vscode to format my python code. I have the extension installed, extension installed
and I have made modifications in setting.JSON file. But I found it not working still. JSON file
"[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": "always"
        },
    },
    "isort.args": [
        "--profile",
        "black"
    ]
}

Also, i tried to rerun the vscode and re-install the extensions, still not work.
For example: Like these lines of code:enter image description here
#to build the tx u just need to call the constructor field
transaction = simplestorage.constructor().build_transaction(
    {
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price, "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    
    }
)

it should be formatted like this enter image description here
# to build the tx u just need to call the constructor field
transaction = simplestorage.constructor().build_transaction(
    {
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price, 
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    
    }
)

but i hit control+s, it turns out that it wasn't. Note that yesterday it can work but I don't know what happened today.
sorry about the image link. I'm newbie here so I'm not able to embed images.

but you are able to copy paste the code in triple back ticks

@rioV8 OH thanks I will modify it

This is not a problem with settings. Your settings can make black work in my vscode. Could you please try to run command Black Formatter: Restart Server after opening your Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) . If restarting the server doesn't work, you can try installing an older version of balck formatter.

@MingJie-MSFT Thanks a lot! I tried to restart server and it worked. I didn't know this until you told me. Anyway thanks for help and have a good day!!

@MingJie-MSFT I have tried it. But don't know if that's correct

This is not a problem with settings. Your settings can make black work in my vscode. Try to run command Black Formatter: Restart Server after opening your Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P).

You could click '✔' to mark my solution as an answer to change its status to Answered.

Solved. Try to run command Black Formatter: Restart Server after opening your Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P). this works for me
